# How to catch set() usage in python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, mocking, introspection, black-box-testing

all this won't work. even changing `side_effect` to something completelly different won't solve a problem.

```
mock = unittest.mock.MagicMock()
with unittest.mock.patch('builtins.set', mock):
    handle = set()

print(mock.called)

import builtins
mock = unittest.mock.MagicMock()
with unittest.mock.patch.object(builtins, "set"):
    handle = set()
```

I actually need somehow to know, if nested function uses some classes\methods\structures. For instance, `set(), tuple(), dict() | {}`.

For instance, it works with `dict()`, but when you use `{}`, there is `False` returns. Is there any convenient way to introspect code in assertions, thinking about it as a black-box?

Comment: Why do you need to know that? Maybe there’s a better approach.

Comment: What is your use case? You can't intercept/mock `[]` and `{}` because they are literals and will bypass global/builtin lookup.

Comment: I have a module. And want to know, if any function inside this module. uses set(), or dict(), etc ... Let me tell you whole. I made a task for students to code functions that behave like a set. Wrote tests, Apart from test, I must know, if anyone cheated and used builtin.set()

Comment: Could you use the ast module on their code to check that way?